# NIntegration and Exclusions

Tags: numerical-integration

I am attempting to integrate a long function by the MonteCarlo method.  The code yields an answer as I've programmed the function, but when I try to define a region of exclusion, I get an error because I am using an inequality to define that region.  Is there a way to accomplish this.

```
α := 1/137.036  
β := 1  
Subscript[m, μ] := 105.6583745000  
Subscript[m, e] := 0.5109989461  
SubPlus[E] := 2 0.0005 Subscript[m, μ]  
Subscript[E, γ] := 2 0.1890 Subscript[m, μ]  
Subscript[x, 0] = 0.0005  
Subscript[x, 1] := 1  
Subscript[y, 0] = 0.189  
Subscript[y, 1] := 1  
Subscript[z, 0] := -1  
Subscript[z, 1] = Cos[π/6]  
Δ[z_] := 1 - β z  
Gvm1[x_, y_] := 
 8 (y^2 (3 - 2 y) + 6 x y (1 - y) + 2 x^2 (3 - 4 y) - 4 x^3)  
Gv0[x_, y_] := 
 8 (-x y (3 - y - y^2) - x^2 (3 - y - 4 y^2) + 2 x^3 (1 + 2 y))  
Gv1[x_, y_] := 2 (x^2 y (6 - 5 y - 2 y^2) 2 x^3 y (4 + 3 y))  
Gv2[x_, y_] := 2 x^3 y^2 (2 + y)  
R[y_] := (2 α)/(
  3 π) (Log[y/2 Subscript[m, μ]/Subscript[m, e]] - 19/12)  
nov[x_, y_, z_] := 
 4 (1 - β^2) ((
 2 x)/Δ[z]^2 (x + y) (2 (x + y) - 3) + (
 x^2 y)/Δ[z] (3 - 4 (x + y)) + x^3 y^2) + 
 Gvm1[x, y]/Δ[z] + 
 Gv0[x, y] + Δ[z] Gv1[x, y] + Δ[z]^2 Gv2[
 x, y]  
f1[x_, y_, z_] := α/(16 π^2 y) (1 - R[y]) nov[x, y, z]  
NIntegrate[
 f1[x, y, z], {x, Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1]}, {y, Subscript[y, 
  0], Subscript[y, 1]}, {z, Subscript[z, 0], Subscript[z, 1]}, 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo", MaxRecursion -> 1000000, 
 Exclusions -> {Δ[z] >= (x + y - 1)/(x*y)}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] Is there a way to accomplish this.

Yes, using `Boole` (and "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"):

```
NIntegrate[
  f1[x, y, z] Boole[Δ[z] < (x + y - 1)/(x*y)], 
  {x, Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1]}, 
  {y, Subscript[y, 0], Subscript[y, 1]}, 
  {z, Subscript[z, 0], Subscript[z, 1]}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]

(* 0.000344527 *)
```

Comment: Outstanding!  Thanks, m_goldberg and Anton!

Comment: @RobinS, no problem, good luck!